# Complex Regex Pattern Combining Numbers with Letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

To search for a specific string, which is like UE-42F5070, in a text with preg_match function I am trying to write a regular expression. I am not able to write the regular expression pattern for "UE-##F####", where #'s are numbers, to use with preg_match to find them in the text.

Example of the string;

`UE-32F5070`
`UE-50F8000`

Comment: I am really not the regex guy, I trying to learn right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number in regex is `[0-9]` or `\d`. Repetitions are `{n}`. So

```
UE-[0-9]{2}F[0-9]{4}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or

```
UE-\d\dF\d\d\d\d
```

Comment: What produced that graphic?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
'/^UE-\d{2}F\d{4}$/'
```

[**Recommended Reading on Regex**](http://regular-expressions.info)

**Details:**

```
^     - Start input
UE    - Match literal "UE"
\d{2} - Match 2 digits
F     - Match literal "F"
\d{4} - Match 4 digits
$     - End input
```

Comment: The only working pattern. (That doesn't match `GROUIK-UE-11F1111-GROUIK`)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like UE is a constant, so you can start your regex with that as a literal, the rest should just be:

`preg_match('/UE-([0-9]{2}F[0-9]{4})/', $string, $matches);`